# programacion sincrona en nodejs, problemas con la asincronia

Tags: javascript, nodejs

llamo desde app.js asi:

```
bd.permitir(req.body.nom,req.body.pass,resultado,bd.insertarLetra);
```

mis funciones con callback son estas:

```
var permitir=function (usuarioNombre,usuarioPass,array,callback){
    var objBD = BD();
    var booleano=1;
    console.log("oooooooooo");
    Object.keys(array).forEach(key => {
    let tiempos  = array[key];
    objBD.query('SELECT nombre from usuario', function(err, rows, fields) {
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            if(rows[i].nombre==usuarioNombre){
                booleano=0;
            }   
        };
    });
    });
    callback(booleano,usuarioNombre,usuarioPass,array);
};

var insertarLetra=function(booleano,usuarioNombre,usuarioPass,array){
    var objBD = BD();
 //insertar usuario mas los datos de las variables

    if(booleano==1){
            var post  = {NOMBRE:usuarioNombre,  PASS:usuarioPass};
            var query = objBD.query('INSERT INTO  usuario SET ?', post, function(err, result) {
                console.log(booleano);
                Object.keys(array).forEach(key => {
                    let tiempos  = array[key];
                    var post  = {ID_U:result.insertId,  LETRA:key};
                    var query = objBD.query('INSERT INTO  LETRA SET ?', post, function(err, result) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < tiempos.length; i++) {
                            var post  = {ID_L:result.insertId,  TIEMPO:tiempos[i]};
                            var query = objBD.query('INSERT INTO  TIEMPOS SET ?', post, function(err, result) {
                            });
                        };
            });
        });
            }); 
    };


    // console.log(query.sql); // INSERT INTO posts SET `id` = 1, `title` = 'Hello MySQL'
};
```

se ejecuta en desorden las funciones!!! como lo soluciono?
quiero que se ejecute primero la funcion permitir y luego insertarLetra

Comment: Un simple setTimeout soluciono el problema que tenia al devolver un array con valores de la base de datos !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lo solucione de esta forma:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    callback(booleano,usuarioNombre,usuarioPass,array);
},3000);
```

no se si sera la mejor manera.

Answer (score 3):

El problema es:

```
callback(booleano,usuarioNombre,usuarioPass,array);
```

Esa línea, que es una ejecución de la función `insertarLetra` se ejecuta en el mismo periodo de tiempo que la consulta.

Lo que debes hacer es mover esa instrucción dentro del callback de tu query. De tal modo que, luego de hacer su proceso, se llame a `insertarLetra`:

```
objBD.query('SELECT nombre from usuario', function(err, rows, fields) {
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    if(rows[i].nombre==usuarioNombre){
      booleano=0;
    }   
  }
  // aquí llamas al callback insertarLetra
  callback(booleano,usuarioNombre,usuarioPass,array);
});
```

Comment: algun buen libro para aprender programacion asincrona, callback,promises ect.

Comment: Eloquent JavaScript, JavaScript the good parts, Understanding EcmaScript 2015 (este año), son buenos libros. El último cubre todo lo que es ES2015: Clases, promesas, destructuring, default params, scoping, etc. También frecuenta blogs como [David Walsh](http://davidwalsh.me) y [Scotch](https://scotch.io).